# Windows 8 x64 crash on wp7 emulator loading

Tags: windows-phone-7, crash, emulation, windows-8

i'm developing on windows phone 7 and i don't have a device so i need to use the emulator for try the app. In Windows 7 i have no problem to work but now i'm migrate to windows 8 and when i launch the emulator the sistem crash and give me the blue screen. I've tried the compatibility mode but nothing change !

How can i use the emulator under windows 8 x64 developer preview?

Comment: Did you have issues getting it installed? The installer never progresses for me. Can you use a device?

Comment: No i've installed all the sdk without issues :( i can't use a device :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone SDK is not supported on Windows 8. There is no official way round this.

Comment: thank you :( ... today i found an msdn guide to make expression blend 4 working on windows 8 and i hoped there were a way to run the emulator too :(

Comment: are there any unofficial way to run wp7 emulator on x64 windows 8 ?? :(

Answer (score 0):

Launching it in windows 7 compatibility mode works for me.

Comment: when i lounch on windows 7 compatibility mode the emulator crash on 64 bit . it works on 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Windows 8, the emulator crashes Windows 7 too if you have VT enabled in the BIOS. Disable it, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try the following
Rename all of the *.dess files under %systemdrive%\programdata\Microsoft\XDE and restart the emulator. it should work.